# Controlling bluetooth transmitter with HTML5 - Javascript app

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth

Briefly, I need to change the value of a bluetooth transmitter which is connected to Arduino. I am programming on Cordova Platform so I use HTML5 and javascript.

Can you suggest any source that I can find information about Bluetooth functions?

Comment: what about [Bluetooth Serial Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial) ?

Comment: [`Navigator`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web)